# JMS Serialize any different property

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xsd

I need to work with some 3rd party API through XML like this

```
  <App:Envelope xmlns:App="http://somenamespace.com/version/1_0">
   <Head/>
   <Body>
     <AppData>
       <method:Auth xmlns:method="http://somenamespace/method/1_0">
          <Login>MyUserName</Login>
          <Password>123456</Password>
       </method:Auth>
     </AppData>
   </Body>
</App:Envelope>
```

i'm use goetas xsd2php for generate class and metadata for JMS Serializer

and this is work fine, but my AppData class has a different type depending on request type and i don't know how to serialize it. I've get XML with empty AppData section

Envelope.php

```
class Envelope
{
    private $header = null;
    private $body = null;
    public function getHeader()
    {
        return $this->header;
    }
    public function setHeader(\HeaderCType $header)
    {
        $this->header = $header;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
    public function setBody(\BodyCType $body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
        return $this;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->body = new BodyCType();
        $this->header = new HeaderCType();
    }

    public function createAuth($login, $password){
        $app = new AppDataType();
        $app->setAuth(new Auth($login, $password));
        $this->body->setAppData($app);
    }           
}
```

AppDataType.php

```
  class AppDataType
    {

    }
```

i've try to use subscribing handler for anyType from goetas xsd2php example, but can't understand how serialize Auth section? Anyone can get me a real example of code how can i do this?

Comment: In this context "JMS" refers to the library's author - Johannes M. Schmitt. However, the _tag_ `jms` refers to the "Java Message Service." Therefore, I'm removing the `jms` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved a problem

```
public function serializeAnyType(XmlSerializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, Context $context)
{

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        $assestor = new \JMS\Serializer\Accessor\DefaultAccessorStrategy();
        $metadata = $context->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataForClass(get_class($value));
        $visitor->getCurrentNode()->appendChild($visitor->createRoot($metadata));
        foreach ($metadata->propertyMetadata as $property) {
            $val = $assestor->getValue($data->{$key}, $property, $context);
            $visitor->visitProperty($property, $val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).